# Customizing a share dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm trying to obtain a share dialog similar to the one below for sharing some plain text with a preselected list of apps (email, Facebook, Twitter, Google+). The problem is that if I launch an intent to share text, the dialog has too many apps.

1) Can I explicitly choose the apps shown in the dialog?

2) If not, I can make a custom dialog. If so, can I specifically choose an app to launch and provide it with my intent? for each dialog option, I'd launch a specific app. First item - email, second item - facebook etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Can I explicitly choose the apps shown in the dialog?

You cannot modify this list that the OS creates with the app chooser.  (I'm guessing that all of these apps accept the **very common** data type "text/plain".)

> 2) If not, I can make a custom dialog. If so, can I specifically choose an app to launch and provide it with my intent? for each dialog option, I'd launch a specific app. First item - email, second item - facebook etc.

As far as building your own custom list, you need to consider a few points:

- You could create Intents that explicitly open the GMail and Facebook apps, but some users don't use these particular apps. Instead you should display apps that accept specific data types (or MIME types).
- Email apps have a specific MIME type: "message/rfc822", but some don't use it. You might be safer using "text/plain".
- I am unaware of any specific Facebook MIME type, you will have to use "text/plain" anyways. Alternatively, you could use the PackageManager to search every installed appfor the string "facebook", however a third party Facebook app might not have this string in its package name....

If you are going to use the "text/plain" data type then you will end up with the list that the OS already automatically created for you...

What you want to do is not impossible, but it is harder than it sounds. In the end you accidentally might exclude the user's favorite app from your customized list...

(Android has an insightful blog on this subject: [Sharing with Intents](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html).)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer.